# Not getting shadows on 3DSMax model

Tags: 3ds-max, shadows, lighting-effects

I created a model of a reception desk in 3DSMax. To light it, I'm using a target light positioned behind the camera angled toward the scene, and one free directional light with the same specs.

The problem is, I'm not getting any shadows in my scene when I render them. I want natural shadows to appear on objects that are being blocked from direct light.

I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your render options. I use c4d and I can turn off shadows for lights or make objects without shadows. Try GI for realistic shadows.

Comment: Also in Maya there are a few places to check, the lights properties, the properties of the object under "Casts Shadows" and in the overall Render settings. See if you are missing something in any of those areas respective to 3DS.

Answer (score 1):

As @komental stated, you can normally adjust the lighting/shadow settings in a couple of places.  I can't speak for 3DS, since I am also a C4D user, but in C4D you adjust the shadow settings via the light object's properties.  You can enable or disable them completely in your render settings.